# read a unicode text file using python

Tags: python, text, lotus-notes, python-unicode

when I read the file it's coming out with all very odd characters special characters I don't understand. How do I get python to read the file in the same way notepad++ does?

the text file came from exporting an email from lotus notes 9 to unicode text.

Comment: can you share some of the text that looks good on notepad++ and not otherwise.

Comment: No, but I can tell you it ends up looking like a different language after I read it in using python and write it to a file? 㤀㨀㐀㄀㨀㄀　 ⬀㄀　　　ഀ ! Nul RecievedL: from Spool/local/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unicode" mode on Windows generally means UTF-16LE with a byte-order marker (BOM). If you're on Python 2.X, open the file with `codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-16')` as described in the Unicode How-To section on [reading Unicode data](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data). If you're on 3.x, you can just use `open(filename, encoding='utf-16')`.

Writing it out again will depend on what encoding you're trying to write to.

Comment: thanks Peter what are text files normally encoded with?

Comment: Totally depends on where they come from. `utf-8` is fairly common, since it's a superset of ascii. But you have to know what your tools are expecting, if you're looking to write the contents back out.